# a simple sum function on pd.DataFrame takes forever when I import my personal library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I cannot show my library for security reasosns but I have a problem where when I import my library, a simple task such as df.sum(axis=1) takes forever.

My library is imported but was never used when I ran df.sum(axis=1) and also interestingly when I do df.sum(axis=0), it runs smoothly and quickly.

If i dont import the library before df.sum(axis=1), it runs fast no problem.

Because even thou the library was imported, it was never used, I dont understand why it affects other parts of the code.

Has anyone had a similar problems?

Comment: It's really hard to tell why unexpected things happen in unknown circumstances. Perhaps, you can give some context about your library without giving up too much of security?

Comment: When imported the code of the library is executed. If not written carefully this can effect other parts of your code. Why this is happening and how to avoid this in your case is impossible to say, if you can't share your code. By the way, code should never contain explicitly secret informations (passwords, app-keys ...).

Comment: I understand it make it very difficult if not impossible to assist without the library detail. My question is that even if the library is executed upon import, it did not interact with the dataframe of interest so how could it possibly affect? the library is a basic ML components using basic libraries such as tensorflow, keras, sklearn, etc.